# "Пять килограмм" или "Пять килограммов"?

Tags: синтаксис, лексическая-сочетаемость

Как правильно?

Comment: Как вам удалось два ответа сделать?

В каких словах? Килограмм и гектар? Ну значит, я неграмотный.

А "сто грамм" вы тоже не принимаете?

Comment: Не "врубился" в Ваш вопрос, уважаемый

Comment: Не врубился в ваш ответ, уважаемый.
Какой вопрос вы не поняли? Про "сто грамм"?

Comment: Сто грамм с приятным партнером почему бы нет?

Comment: А как насчет окончания?

Comment: Наверное, в предложенном контексте окончание неуместно.

Comment: Похоже, докторов филологических наук Аванесова и ЗАлизняка (один автор известнейшего словаря, другой рецензент) тоже надо назвать неграмотными, раз они допускают "5 килограмм".

Comment: В качестве реплики:
Главная особенность нормы – ее динамичность. Если в языке ничего не меняется, значит язык этот мертв. В живом языке постоянно рождаются новые варианты и умирают старые; то, что вчера было недопустимо, сегодня становится возможным, а завтра – единственно верным. И если лингвист видит, что норма меняется, он обязан зафиксировать это изменение (Н.В.Николенкова. Преподаватель филфака МГУ. С портала "Слово". )

Comment: @Ларf, это да, про норму, но не совсем применительно к нашему случаю. "Новая норма" сложилась так давно, что и не вспомнить, едва ли не раньше старой. Тут впору говорить о не о ретроградстве противников "счетного" килограмма и гектара, а о нигилизме

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нигде не встречал помет "разг." применительно к данному правилу. Известно, что слова, обозначающие меру веса, длины, площади и т. д., пишутся с окончанием -ов: килограммов, граммов, фунтов, километров, гектаров, но "сила тока в пять ампер, напряжение 220 вольт". Даже в тестовых вопросах ЕГЭ нарушение данного правила считается ошибкой.

Comment: "Даже в ЕГЭ" в данном случае не совсем корректно. В ЕГЭ действительно из двух вариантов принято выбирать более традиционный - 5 килограммов. Но это не значит, что другой вариант совершенно недопустим.

Answer (score 5):

Если верить Аванесову и/или Зализняку, то форма "килограмм" (а также грамм, гектар и проч.) нормативна при числах и является так называемой счетной формой (по Зализняку - отдельный падеж).

В отношении амперов и вольтов - сомнений нет. Там эта форма (5 вольт, 10 ампер и проч.) единственно возможная. Вот с граммами - сложнее, источники расходятся в оценке. Подозреваю, что правило про меры площадей и весов специально выдумано для "наведения порядка" этаким современным ревнителем "Прожекта о введении единомыслия в России".

К сожалению, авторы вопросов ЕГЭ это не учитывают.

Answer (score 3):

всегда было правильно только килограммов, граммов, кто опускает окончание -- растрелять нахрен и вопросы отпадут.

Comment: Браво!!!Это лучший ответ

Comment: Присоединяюсь! Колом по башке негра/мотных и неряшливых)

Answer (score 2):

Правильно 5 килограммов, граммов. Но в разговорной речи допустимо и 5 килограмм, грамм.

Comment: Возможно, в словарях помет и нет. Однако в  устной речи  речи действует закон экономии речевых усилий и  окончание -ов чаще всего отбрасывается. О допустимости этого в устной речи говорится во многих пособиях по культуре речи, на сайте "gramma" тоже:"  ... можно сказать "пять килограмм помидор". Но только сказать! Писать все-таки следует, согласуясь с нормой: килограммов, помидоров и т. д."

Comment: Чот мне не нравится.  
"Пять помидор" - это понятно, но не пять киллограм **помидор**.

Answer (score 2):

Несколько килограммов, а 11 килограмм. Вне счетной формы — только граммов, килограммов (например: несколько граммов); в счетной форме, то есть в сочетании с числительным корректны оба варианта: грамм, килограмм и граммов, килограммов (100 грамм и 100 граммов, пять килограмм и пять килограммов).

Comment: Правильно, только источники не забывайте указывать. И потом еще такая штука. "Несколько" - тоже может управлять счетной формой. Это тоже своеобразное числительное.

Answer (score 0):

После числительных 5,6,7,8....существительные ставятся в родительном падеже множественного числа.правильно 5киллограмов

Comment: у Розенталя на стр. 443 в справочнике-практикуме за 2005 год пишется: варианты: (десять)граммов/грамм, килограммов/килограмм, каратов/карат.