# С какой буквы писать «Ом» и склоняется ли сокращение?

Tags: сокращения

Насколько я понял, слово «ом» пишется именно так (со строчной) — как «вольт», «ватт», «ампер». А при обозначении единиц в системе СИ она пишется с большой — «Ом» (как и «вольт» — В, «ватт» — Вт, «ампер» — А). Так вот, а как склонять Ом? Никак же?

3 Ом, а не 3 Ом**а**?

Comment: У вас заголовок вопрос не соответствует содержимому. "Сокращение"-то "не склоняется", если это так можно назвать, Это и так ясно. А вот что качается самого слова "ом" в сочетании с числом, то вопрос действительно интересный. Чуть позже отчечу.

Comment: ом, -а, р. мн. омов, ***счетн. ф. ом и омов (ед. измер.)*** «Орфографический словарь Лопатина. http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/info/lop/

Comment: @Серж По ссылке не видно, как найти словарную статью у Лопатина (на "Грамоте" собственная компиляция словарей). Не думаю, что все падежи неограниченно употребимы: "омам", "омами" могу себе представить в тексте, Но для "омов" сложно подобрать убедительный пример, разве что "не хватает _нескольких_ омов (до чего-то)" или иное столь же нестрогое выражение (без конкретного числительного).

Comment: @Alex_ander, достаточно вбить слово в словарь, и статья откроется.

Comment: @Alex_ander Ссылку надо организовать так:  http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BE%D0%BC&all=x -------------- (+) Понимаю, что вопрос не в этом, а в том, что Серж откровенно ленится, но тем не менее...

Comment: *Но для "омов" сложно подобрать убедительный пример* - Ваш пример как раз не очень убедителен. при слове "несколько" употребима именно счетная форма. Аванесов предагает в подобном случае *"не знаю я никаких амперов!". Еще пример - у меня в тексте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Понятно, что слово склоняется, причем речь идет не о каком-то "сокращении" (то есть условном обозначении физической величины - они-то не склоняются, на то они и обозначения), а лишь о падежной форме самого слова при числительном.

Другими словами, как ***произносить*** это сочетание.
*Один ом, два, три четыре ома* - тут все понятно, не склонять невозможно.
Вопрос возникает при форме "пять ом" или "пять омов".
Причем здесь нельзя утверждать, что требуется обычная форма родительного множественного (*пять омов*). Сравните: *Кратные единицы физических величин (ваттов, вольтов, омов) образуются путем присоединения "приставок"  кило, мега и т.д.* (тут в принципе невозможно "ватт, ом или вольт"), однако *"пять вольт"* и *"пять ватт"* выглядит вполне законным.
По аналогии можно рекомендовать и ***"пять ом"***.
Эта так называемая "счетная форма", которая некоторыми лингвистами трактуется как особый падеж.

Подробное её обсуждение, например, здесь. -
["Пять килограмм" или "Пять килограммов"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/7548)
А вообще об особых падежах - [Сколько падежей в русском языке?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/440993)

(+)
На всякий случай.

> 3 Ом, а не 3 Ома?

Разумеется. Если речь идет о ***написании*** этой конструкции, то никаких вариантов тут не может быть. Обозначение физической величины **Ом**, а не "Ома", от падежа это никак не зависит.

(++)
@Alex_ander

> Но для "омов" сложно подобрать убедительный пример,

Держите. Авторство мое.
*Использование омов в качестве единицы сопротивления свзяно с именем физика  Георга Симона Ома....*

Или из нацкорпуса

> Ученые полагают, что обилие «омов» связано с тем, что всякому хочется
> показать, что он занимается чем-то солидным

(Неизвестный)

Но тут я не уверен, о каких омах идет речь.